# Extraer columnas de tabla html con php Dom + curl

Tags: php, html, dom, curl

Hola amigos necesito extraer los valores de las columnas 4 y 5
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy trabajando con curl + dom + php este es el codigo que tengo 
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

```
$url2="https://xyz.com";
$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); //muestra cabecera
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "buscar=&estado=3&etiqueta=0&gestor=0&laccion=0&lote=-1&orden=&tiporden=0&usuario=0");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile); // Cookie aware
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile); // Cookie aware

$content2=curl_exec($ch2); //Ejecuto el curl OK


$html = new simple_html_dom();

$html->load($content2);

    $datos=$html->getElementById('tablaAdministrarOrdenes'); //Obtengo la tabla con el Id


   $ki= strip_tags($datos,"<td>"); //Obtengo los TD de la tabla

  echo $ki; //imprimo los valores
```

Esto es lo que obtengo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito extraer solo los valores de las columnas 4 y 5, como lo puedo hacer?